# Dot graph language - how to make bidirectional edges automatically?

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

Here is a very simplified example of my Dot graph:

```
strict digraph graphName {
A->B
B->A
}
```

This creates
[image]

Instead I want a single edge shown between A and B but with a double arrow head.  I know how to get the double arrowhead as a global option:

```
strict digraph graphName {
  edge [dir="both"]
A->B
B->A
}
```

But that looks very ugly, and not all of my edges should be dual headed.

[image]

If I do more processing of the graph and detect the double reference myself and replace the two edges with a single edge, it looks OK.  But I'd rather not have to do this extra step

```
strict digraph graphName {
A->B [dir="both"]
}
```

[image]

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

How about 'concentrate=true'?:

```
strict digraph graphName {
concentrate=true
A->B
B->A
}
```

[image: with concentrate=true]

From the [documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:concentrate):

> If true, use edge concentrators. This
>   merges multiedges into a single edge
>   and causes partially parallel edges to
>   share part of their paths. The latter
>   feature is not yet available outside
>   of dot.

Comment: Works with a label for me, and I'm running an older version.

Comment: If it helps... this didn't work for me, in so much as it coalesced the edges, but only put a single arrow on the end. Then I tried to "strict digraph"... and it works perfectly then.

Comment: This is silly but it's what the OP wanted, so big up!

Comment: @philw It does not work for me either, I get edges with a single arrowhead only. I am using pygraphviz, and I tried `pgv.AGraph(directed=True, strict=True)`, but it does not work either, i get two edges again... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 130):

You should just use:

```
A -> B [dir=both]
```

Comment: This saved me some redundant lines, and I'm using it as well as the top answer where appropriate.

Comment: You don't need quotes around "both"

Comment: @NoahSussman It can't be the accepted answer because it doesn't actually answer the question ;)