# filter out symmetrical lines by python

Tags: python, regex, graphviz

I have a graphviz file automatically generated, which sometimes produces double connections, e.g.

```
"test textanalysis" -> "development" [color="white"];
"development" -> "test textanalysis" [color="white"];
```

I'd like to know

1) if it is possible to show this as a single connection with double arrows at start&end in Graphviz

2) or in alternative if you know a Python way to filter out one of those lines (I dont mind losing that information): I cannot find a regex able to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this to filter repeating edges:

```
import re

edges = {}

with open(dot_file) as fr:
    for line in fr:
        key = tuple(sorted(re.findall('"([a-z ]+)"', line)[:2]))
        edges.setdefault(key, []).append(line.strip())

for v in edges.values():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print re.sub("\[(.+)\]", '[\\1, dir="both"]', v[0])
    else:
        print v[0]
```

You can also try using `concentrate=true` option (See: [Dot graph language - how to make bidirectional edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462433/dot-graph-language-how-to-make-bidirectional-edges)) for details.

Comment: Interesting python code - but I didnt try it: the concentrate switch which I didnt know did the trick perfectly, thank you!